# How to execute if else unix command from python and get ret value

Tags: python, unix

Following is the code which I am trying to execute using python

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

cmd = 'if (-e "../a.txt") then \n ln -s ../a.txt . \n else \n echo "file    is not present " \n endif'

ret_val = subprocess.call(cmd,shell="True")
```

When executed gives following error message

```
/bin/sh: -c: line 5: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Comment: does the command work in your shell?

Comment: You should be passing `True` to `shell`, not the string `"True"`.

Comment: This is ugly...highly recommend to put the logic into python code instead.

Comment: i am taking unix cmds from seperate file one by one and executing it through python. depending on the return value of previous cmd, i will execute the next cmd. when it reaches the if statement it gives above error and terminates. so i want to know correct way to execute if else statement through python and get return value

Comment: Rather than embedding newlines in your string, just use a semi-colon between commands.  eg, `if [ -e ../a.txt ]; then ln -s ../a.txt .; else echo ...; fi`

Answer (score 6):

In sh scripts, `if` is terminated with `fi`, not `endif`.

http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_01.html

---

Or just write the darn code in Python:

```
import os

if os.path.exists('../a.txt'):
    print 'Exists'
    os.symlink('../a.txt', 'a.txt')
else:
    print 'Does not exist'
```

- [`os.path.exists ()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.exists)
- [`os.symlink()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.symlink)

---

If you really want to run tcsh commands, then:

```
import shlex
import subprocess

args = ['tcsh', '-c'] + shlex.split(some_tcsh_command)
ret = suprocess.call(args)
```

Comment: i am executing in tcsh shell. if run command directly in shell it works. but when i execute through pyhton script its not working.

Comment: Yes this is the way. Dont bother using python if you have more shell cmd than python :D

Comment: No you're not. Look at the error message being printed. It is `/bin/sh`. The shell that *you* are using means nothing here. Passing `shell=True` tells Subprocess to run it via `/bin/sh`.

Comment: ok. want i want to do is, i am giving one cmds file which contains the unix commands and taking each cmd one by one and executing it. when it reaches the if statement it is giving above error

Comment: @SumanthKodali Why are you trying to run a tcsh script through Python, line by line? Why not just run it in the normal way? If you really feel that you must run it inside Python (eg you're passing args & data from Python and you want to post-process the script's output in Python), then you need to _explicitly_ tell subprocess to use tcsh instead of the default sh; that applies whether you're executing it line by line or executing the script as a unit.

Comment: Just put a proper shebang line at the top of your script `#!/bin/tcsh` and `suprocess.call` the thing.....

Comment: i want to automate some tasks so i want to execute it through python. i want to get proper return value from if else. either shell tcsh or sh will do.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart  I tried executing your code. still it gives ret value as 1.

Comment: do i need to execute if else command line by line or should i give whole command in one line?.